Finding a lower bound for $h$ to satisfy $\sum_{i = 0}^{c}(1-\frac{i}{n})^{h}(1 - p)^{n-i}p^{i} {n \choose i}[(i-np)^{2} - np^{2} - i(1 - 2p)] \geq 0$
I have a log-likelihood function which appeared in development of a computational method for biological sequence similarity estimation using k-mers:

This function has several parameters, and I need to show which configuration leads to concavity in a bounded region.
Although the likelihood function itself is quite messy, it boiled down to showing the following:

For which values of $h>1$ as a function of $n$; the following
inequality holds for $p \in \left(0,0.5\right)$ and $0 \leq c \leq n$:



$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{c}\!\!\left(1-\frac{i}{n} \right)^{h}\!\!\left(1 - p\right)^{n - i}p^{i}\!
{n \choose i}\!\!\left[\left(i - np\right)^{2} - np^{2} - i\left(1 - 2p\right)\right]\! \geq\! 0.
$$

It is obvious that for sufficiently large values of $h$, the $i = 0$ term dominates and this becomes positive.
However, I am unable to come up with an expression for $h$, which is simply a parameter of the model.
A lower bound that is not too loose would work fine for my purposes.
I was able to use the expectation of Binomial distribution by moving $\left(1 - i/n\right)^{h}$ out of the summation by using
$$
\left(1-\frac{i}{n} \right)^h \leq
\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^h\quad \mbox{for}\quad i > 0
$$
But that ended up being too loose, and was not useful for realistic choices of $h$
( e.g., $\ 2h < n$ ).


Since the only variable in terms of summation is $i$, sort the term in descending order of $i$ and apply normal distribution.

@RDK I am not sure how to proceed after that.
